# CSS framework for beginner (old browsers)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Sorry for the silly question but I've been looking around on the internet all afternoon with not much success due to the many many frameworks out there (too many).

I am a java web developer who normally doesn't deal with CSS. At my company we have to support ie6 for some stupid reason. I'm looking for a css framework I can use that will get me up and running quickly with some buttons, menu's and layouts and I don't want to just dload any old web template. Would be nice if I took the opportunity to set up the css myself.

Can anyone suggest some good tools/frameworks that will get me up and running quickly? I can't use bootstrap because it does not look compatible with ie6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to build a website which is compatible with **IE 6** (*This is end month of 2013 where it has ie 11*) I recommend using YAML http://www.yaml.de/ . It has clear documentation with examples. You can also use http://www.cascade-framework.com/ which has minimum CSS which required for a website/web application development. Also, YUI you can use http://yuilibrary.com/yui/environments/ .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i don't use any css framewrok supported IE6,but i think older versions of some css framework may support IE6 like http://www.blueprintcss.org you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cascade Framework](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/). It's about as feature rich as Bootstrap and has a grid system more flexible than any other grid systems around.